# 'Personal search engine' - Or a slightly more cross-platform alternative to Fetching.io

Tags: web-apps, web-browser, search-engine, information-management, document-indexing

I came across [fetching.io](http://fetching.io/) on One Thing Well, and it scratches a *pretty* big itch I have. In fact, I basically need something identical - that is to say

- Has a browser extension that keeps track of what websites I go to
- Has a server (self-hosted or not) that lets me full text search these so I can find things

The end result would be a way to find some site I went to but barely remember.

Now, *eventually* Fetching is going to support these but

- Fetching's self-hosted server is OS X only. Not *too* bad (I nearly spun up an instance), but a Linux (or at worst) Windows based server would be better for my needs. At this point, the hosted option meets many of my needs *but* I'd rather not trust a third party with what would be essentially *my entire browsing history*
- <strike>An extension/plugin for *Firefox*. Fetching is only for Chrome and Safari at the moment. This is a bit of a dealbreaker for me</strike>. As of April 3rd 2015, fetching.io has a Firefox extension.

Pretty simple set of basic requirements in theory, but this is the *first* bit of software I've seen that does this.

Extra shiny things I'd like:

- Mobile browser support would be shiny. I use Chrome/Android.
- The ability to *not* index specific sites. For example, I see little need in indexing Gmail or my RSS client.

Comment: See also: [Software (preferably cheap or free) that creates an index / database of every webpage I view online](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14904/60)

Answer (score 1):

Maker of Fetching here. I've got a linux version in the works but could definitely use some help testing it. Please do contact me and I can get you a build to kick around.

Note that we also recently released Cloud Sync -- this let's you sync your bookmarks from a native install to a cloud account so you have access to your bookmarks from anywhere. Along with this we've released a beta version of the API (including DDP support!) which should let you do a lot more with you data.

Finally, we fetching does support URL black listing and all cloud accounts work great on mobile devices.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'd be happy to test out the linux build, but for various reasons, I'd much rather run my own server and sync data from my browsers into it.drop you an email - would the one in your profile do?

Comment: @peter-brown seems you had to drop the project? Or is it open source now? Maybe drop a link here to the new site?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows platform, you can try [Flamory](https://flamory.com). It can save and index pages that you visit, as well as create a snapshots with thumbnails for the pages that you find especially interesting.

It runs locally, and is not dependent on any service. App is free for personal use.

Comment: Dosen't quite seem to work with my current version of firefox

Comment: I use Chrome myself. But, recently received a new version of the app and it said that Latest Firefox support is back.

Answer (score 0):

[Memex](https://getmemex.com/) Does everything op asked for except ignoring sites. But it if open source and includes annotation and tagging. Also exists "historious" though I do not know much about it.