# Software (preferably cheap or free) that creates an index / database of every webpage I view online

Tags: windows, web-browser, document-indexing

I often find myself wanting to look up again something that I looked up previously, but I only remember parts of whatever it is. Running the search through the search engine sometimes helps, but when it does, it takes a long time as the results have either changed or I am typing different keywords this time.

Google Desktop used to do what I wanted it to do, but that has been discontinued. I don't know if I should simply try the programs that were recommended as alternatives, but I would prefer to get a direct answer to my question if there is an answer.

So, to re-iterate what I am looking for: software that indexes or creates a database of the words on every page I view online. Therefore, for example, if months later I remember reading an article with the words interesting and tasty, I can search for those words and the page that had them would come up in the search results in this software. If I searched for those words on a search engine, well the results of that page should also be included. If I could perform different types of searches like exact match, by date, and so on, that would be great.

Software Requirements: Free or cheap and to work on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Do you use a single browser (and if so which), or does the solution has to be independent of the browser?

Comment: Would prefer independent of the browser, but since I mainly use one browser-Firefox-I guess a Firefox only solution would be o.k.

Comment: See also: ['Personal search engine' - Or a slightly more cross-platform alternative to Fetching.io](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13737/60)

Answer (score 3):

I think [Fiddler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_%28software%29) is a good and **free** software for this purpose. It can logs all the pages you have visited, and then you can review them.

As I know it can be configured to capture only a particular application's traffic (Firefox, for example).

Here is a screenshot of Fiddler4:
[image]

And here is another screenshot of its *find/search* tool
[image]

For example I've loaded up Stack Overflow website and then inside Fiddler looked for *stackoverflow* keyword. The search result is something like: (My search options covers both HTTP headers and bodies, if you would like to only search through loaded HTML pages (webpages), you may want to only select bodies as search source)
[image]

[Official Website](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: Does it include an index, and a user interface to search the index?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul What do you mean by *index*? I unfortunately cannot figured out what's your mean

Comment: I mean the same as the original asker. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing The asker wants an interface where he/she would type for instance "tomato", and the app would show all recently seen webpages that contain the word "tomato". Fiddler can't do this, right?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul No, it can well, Fiddler have a *find* tool that looks for a given key phrase through HTTP requests and/or responses. Is it what you want?

Comment: and an example search result? :-) Showing how to access to the webpage found via search.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Done! anything else?

Answer (score -1):

[Flamory](https://flamory.com) does exactly the thing that you described. It saves and indexes every web page or local file that you see, so you can find them later.

You can also make snapshots for interesting pages, and app will save a screenshot and scroll position for that page. Later you can use this snapshot as a bookmark to get back to that place.

App runs on Windows and is free to use.

Comment: I installed it, but its view of my browsing history after installing seemed to be woefully incomplete. If it doesn't catch everything, it's as good as catching nothing.